# Itext : Add Text at bottom of page, if page is full then add it to new page bottom

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I am trying an approach in ITEXT7 to add some note text at bottom of page, but if the page is full of text, then it should add new page and write at bottom of next page, at specific location.

I am applying
 `oc =stamp.getOverContent(i);
oc.showTextAligned(
Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "principle sign", 25, 764, 0);`

I need this to be written at the end of page, but if page is full, then it should be added to new page.
Any idea or suggestion or approach will be great help thanks.

Comment: The update in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53159951/1729265) seems to indicate that what you need is meanwhile quite directly supported.

Comment: Hello @mkl, Thank you for the comment, can you please explain little more, Yes this is static location for adding signature, that's why I am trying to make it dynamic.

Comment: *"can you please explain little more,"* - Well, have you studied the answer I linked to? It sounds like it describes an implementation of what you attempt. If not, please clarify your question because I then clearly misunderstood it... ;)